# Powershell search for any exe in environment path always returns msbuild.exe

Tags: powershell, cakebuild

I am trying to use [Cake](http://cakebuild.net/) as a build tool but am running into an issue in their powershell script.

The script is trying to find `nuget.exe` in the environment variable path. If it doesn't exist it downloads it.

The issue is that `msbuild.exe` is always returned and if `nuget.exe` does not exist the script fails as it tries to us `msbuild.exe`

```
$existingPaths = $Env:Path -Split ';' | Where-Object { (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_)) -and (Test-Path $_) }

$NUGET_EXE_IN_PATH = Get-ChildItem -Path $existingPaths -Filter "nuget.exe" | Select -First 1
```

No matter which `exe`I try to search for using this script even if it exists, `msbuild.exe` is always returned in the list.

Comment: So ... if you run those two pipelines in powershell, `$NUGET_EXE_IN_PATH` contains a fileinfo reference to `msbuild.exe`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes that is right. msbuild.exe is always returned even if I search for monkey.exe. If I search for an exe which does exist msbuild.exe is still included in the returned list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a different and probably more effective check for *nuget.exe* availability

```
if (!(Get-Command nuget.exe -ErrorAction 0)) {
    # nuget.exe is not found, download ...
}
```

As Enrico Campidoglio suggested, you may add `-CommandType Application`. In theory, it should be even more efficient. In (my) practice, this is not always the case.

Comment: For even more _efficiency_, you can add the [`-CommandType Application`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command#-commandtype) parameter to further limit the search scope: `Get-Command -CommandType Application nuget.exe -ErrorAction 0`.

Comment: Not necessarily, I used to profile various commands with and without `CommandType` and found that the latter is often faster, surprisingly. Did you profile this case?

Comment: No, I haven't; when I said _efficiency_ I wasn't talking specifically about _speed_, but rather about the fact that it would have to search fewer locations, namely only the paths in `Path`. This is also the equivalent of what's being done in the Cake bootstrapper script.

Comment: I edited the answer. OP and others may choose. As for myself, I normally do not use this parameter. In particular, this lets to have and use an alias *nuget.exe*, if this is needed for some reason.